# Remove data following the second column

Tags: notepad++, regex

At the moment we are editing one of our databases. We need to remove any info after a second column.

Example of data :

```
abcfrjwf:rhfgpughtep0urt:193.532.456.245
```

I was wondering if anyone knew a regex command for Notepad++ that can make it look like:

```
abcfrjwf:rhfgpughtep0urt
```

If the data is already in this format, for example

```
gtrheppg:rfgeterjyetrtgt
```

it should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with find / replace:

- find what: `([^:]*:[^:]*):.*`
- replace to: `$1`
- make sure to check `regular expression`

This will remove second `:` and everything after it from each line, and it won't change lines without at least two `:`.

[image]